# C# Ninject Web API async query in IAuthenticationFilter causes multiple operations error in entity framework

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api2, ninject

I'm using Web API 2 with Ninject and i'm getting the following error when i've got multiple parallel HTTP calls.

> A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

I didn't get this error before, all the code that retrieves the data from the database is async so i'm thinking its a Ninject scope issue.

**NinjectWebCommon**

```
kernel.BindHttpFilter<MyAuthenticateFilter>(FilterScope.Action);

// Database context
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWorkAsyncFactory>().To<UnitOfWorkAsyncFactory>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWorkAsync>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IDataFactory>().To<DataFactory>().InRequestScope();
```

All the Application and domain handlers are also async and make use of the same `DataFactory` and `UnitOfWorkAsyncFactory`.
**Seems like there's a threading issue with the `IAuthenticationFilter`.**

The factory pattern used for the `DbContext`.

```
public class DataFactory : Disposable, IDataFactory
{
    private MyContext DbContext { get; set; }

    public IDataContextAsync GetDataContext()
    {
        return DbContext ?? (DbContext = new MyContext());
    }

    public void AfterDispose()
    {
        DbContext = null;
    }

    public DataFactory()
    {

    }

    public DataFactory(MyContext context)
    {
        DbContext = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you accidentally fire-and-forget anything `async` instead of awaiting it?

Comment: Not that i can see, the error occurs when trying to read a session entity from the database on the `async Task AuthenticateAsync` method in the `IAuthenticationFilter`. This happens when a http call triggers that reads and returns a file, which also is marked `async`.

Answer (score 0):

I remember some time ago having issues with filter injection in WebApi and scopes being lost.

As far as I remember using this implementation of `IDependencyResolver` (can not remember where I got it) made the issue go away.

```
using System.Web.Http.Dependencies;

using global::Ninject.Syntax;

public class DependencyResolverWebApiNinject : DependencyScopeWebApiNinject, IDependencyResolver
{
    public DependencyResolverWebApiNinject(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
        : base(resolutionRoot)
    {
    }

    public virtual IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Where `DependencyScopeWebApiNinject` is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http.Dependencies;

using global::Ninject;
using global::Ninject.Infrastructure.Disposal;
using global::Ninject.Parameters;
using global::Ninject.Syntax;

public class DependencyScopeWebApiNinject : DisposableObject, IDependencyScope
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DependencyScopeWebApiNinject"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="resolutionRoot">The resolution root.</param>
    public DependencyScopeWebApiNinject(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
    {
        this.ResolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the resolution root.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The resolution root.</value>
    protected IResolutionRoot ResolutionRoot
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the service of the specified type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceType">The type of the service.</param>
    /// <returns>The service instance or <see langword="null"/> if none is configured.</returns>
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        var request = this.ResolutionRoot.CreateRequest(serviceType, null, new Parameter[0], true, true);
        return this.ResolutionRoot.Resolve(request).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the services of the specifies type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceType">The type of the service.</param>
    /// <returns>All service instances or an empty enumerable if none is configured.</returns>
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return this.ResolutionRoot.GetAll(serviceType).ToList();
    }
}
```

hope this will help

Comment: I tried using it but it caused the following error. 'Error activating ModelValidatorProvider using binding from ModelValidatorProvider to NinjectDefaultModelValidatorProvider

A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two services.

Comment: Seems that using this method is deprecated for Web API 2. `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new DependencyResolverWebApiNinject(kernel);`

Comment: @Raybbo unless you are using Ninject's ModelValidatorProvider, you should aslo add this line `kernel.Unbind<ModelValidatorProvider>();` to your NinjectWebCommon file